# Cosmological models other than FRW

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics

The FRW is a nice isotropic and symmetric metric but I think its assumptions are too many. I was wondering about alternative models. Specifically are there any prominent alternatives that have more fleshed out local detail? For example, are there any models that can ascribe a more local interpretation to data which was considered as crucial support for the Big Bang.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious example is the [Hubble bubble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_Bubble_%28astronomy%29) though this doesn't invalidate the FLRW model, it just means the homogeneity is on a larger scale than the observable universe. However I get the impression the Hubble bubble idea is not widely considered likely.

Comment: I don't know of any such theories, or at least none taken seriously by the physics community. There's a good reason the FLRW approximation has survived this long :-) I suppose the axis of evil or the CMB North-South asymmetry (http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0934) might be candidates.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the [Mixmaster Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixmaster_universe), studied in the 1980s. I'll give a couple references:

1. Neil Cornish and Janna Levin, "The mixmaster universe: A chaotic Farey tale". *Phys.Rev. D***55** (1997) 7489–7510. Eprint [arXiv:gr-qc/9612066](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9612066)
2. Charles Misner's original paper "Mixmaster Universe". *Phys. Rev. Lett.* **22** (1969) 1071–1074. DOI:[10.1103/PhysRevLett.22.1071](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103%2FPhysRevLett.22.1071)